# "Сетка(-)рабица" — нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография, этимология

Что-то зависла я на этом слове. Чисто интуитивно я бы дефис поставила, но, с другой стороны, рабица — это просто вид сетки (кстати, интересно бы узнать этимологию этого слова).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

От нем. Rabitzgewebe — конструкционный материал. Названа по имени немецкого изобретателя Карла Рабитца (нем. Carl Rabitz), который придумал её  как основу для оштукатуривания стен. Патент на изобретение был получен в 1878 году. По другим источникам, плетёную сетку изобрел Чарльз Бернард из Норвича (Великобритания) в 1844 году.

http://pda.gramota.ru/?action=buro&page=25&s=%FD%F2%E8%EC%EE%EB%EE%E3%E8%FF
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=*%F0%E0%E1%E8%F6%E0&all=x

Орфографический словарь
рабица, -ы, тв.  -ей

сетка-рабица, сетки-рабицы

Правда, в Википедии почему-то сетка Рабица, как сетка кого?-  Рабица.Может, поначалу она так и воспринималась, но теперь только сетка-рабица.

Comment: И до сих пор помнят изобретателя :

> Анна Соколова. Взгляд из дома: что новенького? (2002) // «Биржа плюс свой дом» (Н. Новгород), 2002.11.18 **Сетка Рабитца** тоже в какой-то степени hi-tech. (Нацкорпус)